# Many2Many Relathionship. Mapping error?

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, eclipselink, relation

im having a problem with a many2many relation. Im using **MySQL**, with **EclipseLink JPA 2**. Ive been reading a lot, and cant figure out why the Join Table never updates!!
I have more Many2many Relation in the projject which are working perfectly, but cant fix this one. Can any1 tell me which the error is.???

```
Expediente.java

@JoinTable(name = "expediente_tiene_partepolicial", joinColumns = {
@JoinColumn(name = "PK_IdDelicuente", referencedColumnName = "PK_IdDelicuente")},      inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PK_CodParte", referencedColumnName = "PK_CodParte")})
@ManyToMany
private List<PartePolicial> partePolicialList;


PartePolcial.java

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "partePolicialList")
private List<Expediente> expedienteList;
```

Comment: Can you add code which demonstrates how you add to the relationships?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are adding to both sides of the relationship.